# rkhunter warning about ssh root access when that access is not allowed on the system

Tags: ssh, security, root, rkhunter

I just ran `rkhunter --check` and all was good except this:

```
Checking if SSH root access is allowed                   [ Warning]
```

What does this warning mean? SSH root access is not allowed on this system.

EDIT #1

Here is how my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is set:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

and `rkhunter.conf`

```
root ~ # cat /etc/rkhunter.conf | grep  ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER
#ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER=no
ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER=unset
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following values need to match:

1. In `rkhunter` configuration:

   ```
   cat /etc/rkhunter.conf | grep ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER
   ```

   > ```
   > ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER=no
   > ```
2. In `sshd` configuration:

   ```
   cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep PermitRootLogin
   ```

   > ```
   > PermitRootLogin no
   > ```

Once they do match, you should not be warned by `rkhunter` any longer.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the edit!  Still getting used to the editor.

Answer (score 5):

In case you have set in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Again in the `/etc/rkhunter.conf` the value must match, as in the following example:

```
ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER=without-password
```

Comment: Everywhere I read, it is specified that (in case of Ubuntu), you should write: ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER=yes, but that doesn't work. This answer solves it! Thanks!