# rkhunter giving ssh root login warning even when both config files are set to "no" root login

Tags: linux, centos, rkhunter

I'm getting a warning from `rkhunter`, even though the `sshd` and `rkhunter` options for **root login** are both set to "no". Running Centos 7.6.1810 with rkhunter 1.4.6.

Here are grep results which verify that the `sshd` and `rkhunter` config settings are both set to "no":

```
$grep PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config  
PermitRootLogin no
```

```
$grep ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER /etc/rkhunter.conf    
ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER=no
```

For clarity, note that the protocol options are set as follows:

```
$grep Protocol /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Protocol 2
```

```
$grep ALLOW_SSH_PROT_V1 /etc/rkhunter.conf
ALLOW_SSH_PROT_V1=0
```

The `rkhunter` log clearly shows that `sshd` and `rkhunter` config are both set to indicate **no root login**, yet I get a warning about ssh root access:

```
[13:43:33] Info: Using configuration file '/etc/rkhunter.conf'

[13:48:21] Info: Starting test name 'system_configs_ssh'  
[13:48:21]   Checking for an SSH configuration file          [ Found ]  
[13:48:21] Info: Found an SSH configuration file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config  
[13:48:21] Info: Rkhunter option ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER set to 'no'.  
[13:48:21] Info: Rkhunter option ALLOW_SSH_PROT_V1 set to '0'.  
[13:48:21]   Checking if SSH root access is allowed          [ Warning ]  
[13:48:21] Warning: The SSH and rkhunter configuration options should be the same:  
[13:48:21]          SSH configuration option 'PermitRootLogin': no  
[13:48:21]          Rkhunter configuration option   'ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER': no  
[13:48:21]   Checking if SSH protocol v1 is allowed          [ Not allowed ]  
[13:48:21]   Checking for other suspicious configuration settings [ None found ]
```

Similarly, the email I receive from rkhunter gives me a warning, yet it also confirms that the settings are already the same:

```
---------------------- Start Rootkit Hunter Scan ----------------------
Warning: The SSH and rkhunter configuration options should be the same:
         SSH configuration option 'PermitRootLogin': no
         Rkhunter configuration option 'ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER': no

----------------------- End Rootkit Hunter Scan -----------------------
```

Any ideas of what is causing this `rkhunter` warning and how to fix it??

Comment: did you change `ALLOW_SSH_PROT_V1` this option from default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rkhunter warning about ssh root access when that access is not allowed on the system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194087/rkhunter-warning-about-ssh-root-access-when-that-access-is-not-allowed-on-the-sy)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and formatting @Bart, but I don't believe that this is a duplicate. In my case, the config options in rkhunter and sshd_config are both set to "no" as shown.

Comment: @HosseinVatani I have edited the query to show the protocol settings.

Comment: Does the config parser care about trailing whitespace (after `no`)? Are both files Unix text files (not DOS text files)?

Comment: I guessed this is a bug. I suggest reporting it to rkhunter or centos team.

Comment: @Kusalananda you are right. Somehow the shh_config file has ended up with DOS ^M line endings, which `rkhunter` recognizes as a mis-match. I used `cat -A /etc/ssh/sshd_config` to see the problem. Thanks!

Comment: As you're new on this site, please don't edit your question to include `[Solved]` but instead don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of  [the answer that is the most useful of all](/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

[As it turned out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534476/rkhunter-giving-ssh-root-login-warning-even-when-both-config-files-are-set-to-n/534757#comment990622_534476), the `sshd_config` file was a DOS text file.  As a consequence of this, the value assigned to the `PermitRootLogin` setting (as parsed by `rkhunter`) was not `no` but `no\r` (the carriage return from the DOS line ending would have been part of the value for the option).

This in turn meant that the values for `PermitRootLogin` and `ALLOW_SSH_ROOT_USER` compared as different, even though the two strings' representation in the terminal looked the same.

Comment: While it remains unclear how the `sshd_config` file ended up with DOS line endings, I made the incorrect assumption that using 'vim` on my Centos 7 server would apply the correct line ending when I edited the`sshd_config` file. But, apparently vim is so "smart" that it preserved the erroneous line endings. Viewing the file with 'cat -A /etc/ssh/sshd_config` clearly showed the error. And using `:set fileformat` in `vim` would have also showed the problem in this case.